# Pick which WHERE(Condition) to use based on another WHERE(Condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on existing PIVOT table. I want to select based on (select which) column value. To select the which column, it is based on another condition. I give you example:

```
@InputCharacter;

Select * from Table_A 

IF @InputCharacter  = 'a'
WHERE column_1 = 1 --Use this condition if @InputCharacter equal to a

ELSE IF @InputCharacter  = 'b'
WHERE column_2 = 1 --Use this condition if @InputCharacter equal to b

ELSE
WHERE column_3 = 1 --Use this condition if @InputCharacter equal to other value
```

I try to search on web and Stackoverflow, but maybe I dont know the perfect keyword to use for search, so I came to ask this question.

Comment: Awesome username. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `OR` or `CASE`

```
-- 1
SELECT *
FROM Table_A
WHERE (@InputCharacter = 'a' AND column_1 = 1)
   OR (@InputCharacter = 'b' AND column_2 = 1)
   OR (ISNULL(@InputCharacter,'') NOT IN ('a','b') AND column_3 = 1)

-- 2
SELECT *
FROM Table_A
WHERE
    CASE
      WHEN @InputCharacter = 'a' THEN IIF(column_1 = 1,1,0)
      WHEN @InputCharacter = 'b' THEN IIF(column_2 = 1,1,0)
      WHEN column_3 = 1 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END = 1

-- 3
SELECT *
FROM Table_A
WHERE
    CASE @InputCharacter
      WHEN 'a' THEN IIF(column_1 = 1,1,0)
      WHEN 'b' THEN IIF(column_2 = 1,1,0)
      ELSE IIF(column_3 = 1,1,0)
    END = 1
```